# Passing A Function As Argument To A Function

Tags: javascript

```js
function say(something) {
  console.log(something);
}

function exec(func, arg) {
  return func(arg);
}

exec(say, "Hi, there.");
```

Why does this code work? I feel like it shouldn't since what is in the second function should return

```
say(something) (arg) { 
  console.log(something) ; 
}
```

Comment: actually the question is unclear. what do you want and what does not work?

Comment: @NinaScholz i dont understand why the code returns Hi, there.

Comment: say(something) (arg) { 
console.log(something) ; 
}  <-- this to me is a problem @NinaScholz

Comment: "i dont understand why the code returns Hi, there" ...it doesn't _return_ that value, it logs it to the console _inside_ the say() function. If you logged the _output_ of `exec(say, "Hi, there.");` it would be undefined.

Comment: the second one is no valid javascript.

Comment: yes i know so why doesnt this code cause an error to pop up in the console? -> function say(something) {
  console.log(something);
}

function exec(func, arg) {
  return func(arg);
}

exec(say, "Hi, there.");               func = say(something) {console.log(something) ;} and arg = "Hi, there" @NinaScholz

Comment: it doesn't error because there's nothing wrong with it. What do you _think_ is wrong with it? Where would you expect it to error? Have you looked at the answers below, maybe they'll help explain what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as it does because when you write `return func(arg);`, the `func(arg)` bit *executes* the function. What is returned is then the *result* of executing `func(arg)`.

However, you're right that `say()` doesn't actually return a value, it just logs to the console within that function. The output you're seeing is the result of that log command. If you logged the returned value instead you'd see `undefined` as the result.

But if you'd passed a different function to `exec` which *did* return a value, then you'd need the `return` in `exec()` for it to work properly.

P.S. I'm not sure if this is part of what you're asking, but the difference between that and when you wrote `exec(say, "hi there");` is that in that code, `say` is a *reference to* the "say" function. At that moment it's treated like any other variable, just the same as if you passed in a number or a string, for example.

The difference is the `()`, which causes the function to be executed, rather than passed as a reference.

In the question you seem to imply that you'd expect the source code of the say() function to be displayed, but this is not what it does, and also is not possible anyway.

Comment: so the second function returns say(("Hi, there.")) {console.log("Hi,there.") ;} ?

Comment: Sort of. It returns the _result_ of executing `say("Hi, there.")`. In this case, that result happens to be `undefined`, because the `say()` function does not return any value.

Comment: Imagine instead of `return func(arg);` you had written `var result = func(arg); return result;`. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: ok i see but dont you need the next two characters => to pass an anonymous function

Comment: You mean this syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions ? no, you don't _need_ that, that's a different way of defining a non-reusable function (and it has, in certain circumstances, different behaviours which you should be careful about).

Answer (score 1):

Function say returns undefined (default value if no return keyword is used), and therefore function exec also returns undefined.

Proof:

```js
function say(something) {
  console.log(something);
}

function exec(func, arg) {
  var result = func(arg);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

var result2 = exec(say, "Hi, there.");
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: thank you for the help i will upvote your post as soon as i can

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a closure, where `exec` returns a function for getting `arg` for the first handed over function `func`.

```js
function say(something) {
    console.log(something);
}

function exec(func) {
    return function (arg) {
        return func(arg);
    };
}

exec(say)("Hi, there.");
```

Comment: i dont know what a closure is but i will learn about them and upvote your post as soon as i can. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @6Michael6Myers6 Basically in this case the closure is a neater (and maybe cleverer) way of writing `function say(something) {
    console.log(something);
}

function exec(func) {
    var f = function (arg) {
        return func(arg);
    };
    return f;
}

var newFunc = exec(say);
newFunc("Hi, there");`. That might help you to understand what is happening here. In your simple example it's not massively useful, but would have more value if exec() was doing more work. See https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4 for examples.

Comment: @ADyson just finished reading about closures on mdn now im a read the article you gave me a link to thank you